# How to disable "note:" hints for msvc c++ compiler

Tags: c++, visual-c++, compiler-warnings

I'm using msvc cl.exe directly without visual studio and would like to have an easy way to read warnings and errors. I have quite complicated template setup and when i receive some warning or errors i have to scroll through wall of compiler output like

```
/internal/include/internal/scene/states/scene_events.h(32): error C2440: 'static_cast': cannot convert from 'game::events::random_event' to 'float'

/helpers/tsm/include/tsm/internal/actions.h(55): note: see reference to function template instantiation 'void game::internal::playing_event::receive_event::operator ()<FSM,OutState>(game::events::random_event &&,FSM &,InState &,game::internal::playing_event &) const' being compiled
    with
    [
        FSM=tsm::back::internal::machine_base<game::internal::scene_fsm>,
        OutState=game::internal::ready,
        InState=game::internal::ready
    ]
/helpers/tsm/include/tsm/internal/actions.h(54): note: while compiling class template member function 'void tsm::actions::internal::action_invocation<Action,FSM,Event,InState,OutState>::operator ()(Event &&,FSM &,InState &,OutState &) const'
    with
    [
        Action=game::internal::playing_event::receive_event,
        FSM=tsm::back::internal::machine_base<game::internal::scene_fsm>,
        Event=game::events::random_event,
        InState=game::internal::ready,
        OutState=game::internal::playing_event
    ]
....
```

and so on and so on. are there any options to disable "note:" output?
i didn't find any in [official docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/compiler-options-listed-by-category?view=vs-2017)

Comment: Learn to love those notes. They are of tremendous help.

Comment: I love them, they help alot in some situations. But in some cases i don't care about them. The question is not about liking or hating them, it's about having an option to disable them)

Comment: There is none. That's why you have to love them.

Comment: gcc has `-Wfatal-errors` that will stop at the first error.  Not sure if MSVS has something similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for being the bearer of the bad news, but there is no way to disable those notes output from the compiler diagnostics.

There are (were) some filtering 3rd party tools, but discussing those would be offtopic.

Comment: I don't think 3rd party tools are off-topic in answers, as solutions to the problem being asked about. It's just that directly *asking* for tool recommendations is off topic.

Comment: You can certainly recommend some tool to address the question.

Comment: stockholm syndrome it is. gonna love it.
as for tools - i'm ok with awk for that matter: `gawk '/^\s*with$/{if(n)s=1} {n=/note:/?1:0} !(n||s); /]/{s=0}'`